# How to try "Encrypt secret data at rest" feature in GKE

Tags: encryption, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

K8s has this feature to [encrypt secret data](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/), which requires modification of kube-apiserver config, how can i do this in GKE?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/default-encryption/ maybe you'll find that helpful

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is, you can't.

The Kubernetes Engine master is managed by Google, so you can't change its runtime parameters. Nonetheless, while the data may not be encrypted inside the etcd running on the master node, [the contents of the master node itself are encrypted](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/default-encryption/#encryption_of_data_at_rest) as the link Will pointed to explains.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can, now. From the latest `gcloud` release notes:

```
### Kubernetes Engine

* Promoted the `--database-encryption-key` flag of `gcloud container clusters 
create` to beta. The flag enables support for encryption of Kubernetes Secrets.
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes